# I have an instance of RDS of MySQL 5.7.10

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-5.7, amazon-ec2

I do not understand why memory bar seems to exceed to the red zone with 24.5 MB while RDS server should be with 1Gib[image]

Comment: That looks like 24.5 MB **free** memory (so, approximately 999.5 MB of 1024 MB is not free).  Check the monitoring graphs?  Click Instance Monitoring, Single Metric, and check that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `performance_schema` enabled, then this will consume roughly 500Mb of RAM, then in addition to that you need to take into account your buffer pool size settings (RDS defaults these to 3/4 of the RAM).

Adding these two together can push the allocated ram size over 1Gb quite quickly - note that you have 182Mb of swap used too.

The 24.5Mb of free RAM is probably the OS file cache, which can be discarded by the OS should other RAM demands become too much.

Try turning off the `performance_schema` in the RDS parameter group and see if that makes any difference.